# Move description under image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

How can I move the short description under the image on the single product page?
[Here](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-booking/)'s an example.

Comment: Do you want to short description here http://screencast.com/t/rgi6VRvM ?

Comment: You have this theme up and running over a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'custom_single_product_short_description', 40 );
function custom_single_product_short_description(){
    the_excerpt();
}
```

Would you please try above code? I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` does not work anymore. Better is `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary ` can work in that case or any other position one is trying to move it into - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score -1):

Put this code at your theme's `functions.php` file and you get your result.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
```